# Question regarding measurable map and doubt clearing

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Suppose a map $T:\Omega_1\rightarrow\Omega_2$ and $\sigma$-fields $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$.

Define $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2 = \{T^{-1}A_2 | A_2\in \mathcal{F}_2\}$ and $T\mathcal{F}_1 = \{A_2 | T^{-1}A_2\in \mathcal{F}_1\}$

Now it is easy to show that $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2$ and $T\mathcal{F}_1$ are a $\sigma$-fields. But now my aim is show $T$ is $\mathcal{F}_1/\mathcal{F}_2$ measurable if and only if $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2\subset \mathcal{F}_1$ and to $\mathcal{F}_2\subset T\mathcal{F}_1$.

**My approach**

(*Only if part*) Given $T$ is measurable $\mathcal{F}_1/\mathcal{F}_2$ that imply $T^{-1}A_2 \in \mathcal{F}_1$ for each $A_2\in \mathcal{F}_2$

Therefore $T^{-1}\mathcal{A}_2 \subset \mathcal{F}_1$ for each $\mathcal{A}_2\subset \mathcal{F}_2$ for a arbitrary collection of set $\mathcal{A}_2$ but **I cannot show that $\sigma\{T^{-1}\mathcal{A}_2\}$ = $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2$.**
then we can conclude that $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2\subset \mathcal{F}_1$.

and from definition of measurable map, $A_2\in \mathcal{F}_2\Rightarrow T^{-1}A_2\in \mathcal{F}_1$
Therefore  $A_2\in T\mathcal{F}_1$ then $\mathcal{F}_2\subset T\mathcal{F}_1$.(**is this right conclusion?**)

(*if part*) Given that $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2\subset \mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2\subset T\mathcal{F}_1$.

$T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2\subset \mathcal{F}_1 \iff A_2\in\mathcal{F}_2\Rightarrow T^{-1}A_2\in\mathcal{F}_1$.............(1)

and

$\mathcal{F}_2\subset T\mathcal{F}_1 \iff T^{-1}A_2\in\mathcal{F}_1\Rightarrow A_2\in \mathcal{F}_2$..................(2)

Therefore from (1) and (2) we can say that $T$ is measurable. (**Is my logic correct?**)

New short approach appreciable. **Thanks in advance**

Comment: to put `{` and `}` in $\LaTeX$ you must write `\{` and `\}` respectively

Comment: I cannot understand your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to prove that:
$T$ is $\mathcal{F}_1/\mathcal{F}_2$ measurable if and only if $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2\subset \mathcal{F}_1$ if and only if $\mathcal{F}_2\subset T\mathcal{F}_1$.

Proof. $T$ is $\mathcal{F}_1/\mathcal{F}_2$ measurable if and only if, for each $A_2\in \mathcal{F}_2$, $T^{-1}A_2 \in \mathcal{F}_1$ , that means,
$$T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2 = \{T^{-1}A_2 | A_2\in \mathcal{F}_2\}\subset \mathcal{F}_1$$

So we have proved the first equivalence.

Now let us prove that  $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2\subset \mathcal{F}_1$ if and only if $\mathcal{F}_2\subset T\mathcal{F}_1$. We have

\begin{align*}
T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2\subset \mathcal{F}_1 & \Leftrightarrow 
\{T^{-1}A_2 | A_2\in \mathcal{F}_2\} \subset \mathcal{F}_1 \\
& \Leftrightarrow 
\textrm{for all } A_2\in \mathcal{F}_2, T^{-1}A_2 \in  \mathcal{F}_1\\
&\Leftrightarrow 
\mathcal{F}_2 \subset \{A_2 | T^{-1}A_2\in \mathcal{F}_1\} \\
& \Leftrightarrow 
\mathcal{F}_2\subset T\mathcal{F}_1
\end{align*}

**Remark**: We have proved the $T$ is $\mathcal{F}_1/\mathcal{F}_2$ measurable if and only if $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2 \subset \mathcal{F}_1$.

So $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that we can take in $\Omega_1$ that make $T$ is $\mathcal{F}_1/\mathcal{F}_2$ measurable.

If we take $\mathcal{F}_1$ to be smaller that $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2$, then $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2\subset \mathcal{F}_1$ no longer holds and $T$ will not be  $\mathcal{F}_1/\mathcal{F}_2$ measurable.

Comment: Nice approach.... now just for a clearance... is $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2$ is smallest sigma field?

Comment: @annie_lee  Yes. $T^{-1}\mathcal{F}_2$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that we can take in $\Omega_1$ that make $T$ is $\mathcal{F}_1/\mathcal{F}_2$ measurable. I added a remark to my answer. Please, let me know if it is clear.

Comment: Thanks.... It's clear to me